# CSS not removing overlapping / thickened borders

Tags: html, css

Line 5 in the CSS removed all of the overlapping or thickened lines but through the middle, the line is still thick and at the start of the 2nd column as you can see in the picture but it isn't in the tutorial I'm watching. Why?

[image: Screencap of table]

```css
/* table styles */

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* end table styles */
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>$3.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Celery</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>$5.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garlic</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>$13.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marbles</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>$23.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VERY LONG ITEM THAT MAKES THE HEADER GO BRR</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>$40.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see a picture. You can edit your question to add it. Also could you make your code into a snippet we can run, it makes helping much easier. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Ooo I didn't realise gimme a sec to add it

Comment: Thanks. I think you are seeing an edge effect - when the system has to decide how to show things when there are part pixels involved (on modern screen several sceen pixels are used for one CSS pixel and some can get 'left behind' when there are fractions involved - bit like rounding errors). To test this try zooming in and out to see if the thick lines change position. On my Windows10 Edge the first one was below Garlic then when I zoomed thick lines appeared elsewhere.

Comment: Works perfectly for me at zoom level 0 (actual size), but as I zoom in I do see these some of the borders become thicker than others.

Comment: @AHaworth Yess the position changes when I zoom in or disappears entirely! Thanks for that. Is there anyway to fix it though?

Comment: @BrettDonald Yeah that's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @AHaworth Idk if this helps but I opened the file on internet explorer and I can't spot the problem there. What does the browser got to do with this?